# Why is my GET response undefined when I try to use map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, array.prototype.map

I want to take a request and map the data into a list.  I can at least see the data in the console until I try to use the `.map()` function, and then all of a sudden, data is undefined.

Here is my code,

```
function App() {

  const [clients, setClients] = React.useState(null);


    React.useEffect(() => {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/client/list')
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(data => {
          setClients(data.clients);
        });
    }, []);

console.log(clients)

clients.map((client) => (

    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
  <p key={clients._id}>{clients.DisplayName}  </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  ))
}

export default App;
```

So if  I replace everything after the `console.log(clients)` then I can at least see my request in the console and a 200 response with json in the Network tab

Comment: Your error is clearly stating that you're trying to find a `name` property on undefined, check once again are you using proper keys for accessing object values

Comment: Open the Network pane and inspect the actual response there. You’re almost certainly going to find that it’s an HTML document. When you see that *“SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0”*, it pretty much always means you’ve gotten an HTML response rather than a JSON response. Use the Network pane to also check the HTTP status code of the response. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: well, thats the weird thing.  The API request doesn't show up in the Network panel when I uncomment the map function.  But it does say 304

Comment: I think to get more help you need to show more of your code. How are you getting `clients`? Your fetch call isn’t populating any `clients` variable. From the snippets currently as-is in the question, there’s no relationship between the fetch call in the first snippet, and the `clients.map(…‚)` call in the second snippet.

Comment: That JSON isn't valid. There are multiple issues that are causing it to fail to parse. You'll need to make changes to the backend to fix it

Comment: This feels more about what _you_ still need to do: there's plenty to debug here: your client-side code is 100% irrelevant if you're testing your GET operation, so remove it from the question and show what an actual normal GET requestion does based on typing that URL in your browser URL bar, or based on what cURL does. Also, you're showing both client side code, and server side code, and an error: which of the two throws the error? Because the other part is not currently relevant. You have some methodical work left to do here, before we can meaningfully help.

Comment: Everything I've posted is from the react side.  Postman, web browser, and curl output are all returning the data that I expect right out of mongo. jsonlint.com says its valid JSON.  I think I've done a bad job of explaining my problem and made it more complicated.  I'm going to take a break from this issue for now and come back at it with fresh eyes.  I appreciate everybody's' input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving clients from an asynchronous network request. This data you retrieve is not available till the 2nd render cycle triggered by your `setClients` call. The first time this view is rendered clients is null. Accessing `clients.map` throws an error because there is no map function on a `null`. You can leverage the logical `&&` operator to check for nulls before you map the value. Additionally, your syntax is incomplete. Change your code to,

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
       {clients && clients.map((client) => (<p key={client._id}>{client.DisplayName}</p>)}
      </header>
    </div>
  )
```

This will ensure that the `clients.map` call will only run when clients is not null. This technique is known as [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator). I recommend you read this and the other guides at [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org).